# How to open another url link in sharepoint 2013 body?

Tags: hyperlink

I want to show other external link data within my SharePoint 2013 site body. How I can do? I want my sharepoint 2013 site header and footer. Only body container should display other link data. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Page Viewer Web Part to display a Web page, file, or folder on a SharePoint page. You enter a hyperlink, file path, or folder path to link to the content.

[image]

For more information check below link:
[Display a Web page on a SharePoint page by adding the Page Viewer Web Part](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Display-a-Web-page-on-a-SharePoint-page-by-adding-the-Page-Viewer-Web-Part-7F61FEEC-9B3D-4805-A960-07636BA59527)

Comment: But its a frame tag output. I don't want like that, I want to show content of another url as part of sharepoint body-container. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page

Comment: Thank you. Now I want to increase height of pageviewer frame. CSS not working on it.